# How can I call a function every 3 seconds for 15 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I call a jQuery function every 3 seconds?

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    //do stuff...

    $('post').each(function()
    {
        //do stuff...
    })

    //do stuff...
})
```

I'm trying to run that code for a period of 15 seconds.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

None of the answers so far take into account that it only wants to happen for 15 seconds and then stop...

```
$(function() {
    var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        //  Do whatever in here that happens every 3 seconds
    }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }, 18000);
});
```

This creates an interval (every 3 seconds) that runs whatever code you put in the function.  After 15 seconds the interval is destroyed (there is an initial 3 second delay, hence the 18 second overall runtime).

Comment: +1, but you probably want to increase the `15000` somewhat; otherwise the function will most likely run only four times, and I'm guessing the intent is that it be run five times.

Comment: Good point - it should be at least 18000.  Answer modified - thanks :)

Comment: Er, I was thinking more like `15500` -- just enough to give a nice margin of error.

Comment: Then I don't understand -- why did you make it `18000`?

Comment: Wow - blast from the past!  Okay, you need to set the timeout to clear the interval after 18 seconds as the `do whatever` part will not run until 3 seconds has passed.  If you set it for less than 18 seconds then it won't actually run for 15.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` to run a function after X milliseconds have passed.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $('post').each(function(){
        //do stuff...
    });
}, 3000);
```

Or, `setInterval` to run a function every X milliseconds.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    $('post').each(function(){
        //do stuff...
    });
}, 3000);
```

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` return IDs, these can be used to clear the timeout/interval using `clearTimeout` or `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 3 seconds
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setInterval` function.

```
var doPost = function() {
  $('post').each(function() { 
    ...
  });
};
setInterval(function() { doPost(); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the setTimeout method also, which supports things like cancelling the timer.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Dont downvote this, it can be used with a recursive call. Though setinterval is more correct in this case. Simon: Theres a clearinterval method as well btw :)

Comment: Yeah, crap answer... deleting :-)

Comment: @Aliostad - interesting, what makes setTimeout better?