# CSS3 3d Flip with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Using this great flip tutorial, http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/ how would I modify the code to have the image flip every 3 seconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I call a function every 3 seconds for 15 seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991095/how-can-i-call-a-function-every-3-seconds-for-15-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd change the hover state to be on a class rather than on the :hover selects, then use JavaScript to set a timer and toggle the class with jquery.

I'm on my iPad, but look up setinterval in JS and toggleClass in jQuery. Anyone else, feel free to edit this to add the code!